# SSH running sh script that works locally but not remotely

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to run a script that will be called by some other software to run some parameters to get out objective values.

The script run.sh is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e 
ssh id@somehost '
/path/to/folder/solver arg1 arg2 arg3
res=$(</path/to/folder/res_data.txt)
echo "Final Result:"
echo "1 $res"
'
```

Running this file results in the following:

```
$ sh run.sh
OpenNN Exception: NeuralNetwork class.
void load(const std::string&) method.
Cannot load XML file ../data/neural_network.xml.

Final Result:
1 -285361 3.22136
Connection to somehost closed.
```

The Final Result above is from a previous output

If I run a similar script without the ssh

```
set -e 
/path/to/folder/solver arg1 arg2 arg3
res=$(</path/to/folder/res_data.txt)
echo "Final Result:"
echo "1 $res"
```

Results in

```
$ sh run.sh 7 26 100
Final Result:
1 -285361 3.22136
$ sh run.sh 7 26 150
Final Result:
1 -421429 5.16397
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Does `../data/neural_network.xml` exist on the remote server?

Comment: ERROR: "Cannot load XML file ../data/neural_network.xml"
You need change dir before line "/path/to/folder/solver arg1 arg2 arg3".

Comment: @JNevill the ../data/neural_network.xml does not exist on remote server, but what Šerg suggested worked. I will post an answer.

Comment: @Šerg your suggestion worked thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above the solution of the error I was getting,

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e 
ssh id@somehost '
cd /path/to/folder/
./solver '$1' '$2' '$3'
res=$(<./res_data.txt)
echo "Final Result:"
echo "1 $res"
'
```

I was simple enough just to add `cd /path/to/folder/` and run the script from the folder it seems to work, in addition I also fixed the issue with the arguments  rather than `./solver $1 $2 $3`, having `./solver '$arg1' '$arg2' '$arg3'` as the way to pass the inputted arguments to run on the solver.

The following output is from the corrected file above

```
$ sh run.sh 7 26 100
Final Result:
1 -285361 3.22136
$sh run.sh 7 26 150
Final Result:
1 -421429 5.16397
```